# I have a problem rendering children of an object with React and Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I have a problem rendering the children of an object with React and Redux.

Here is the code.

> When i get the data of a specific ID, everything works perfectly except for an object that i named as `talla_L` which sends me an undefined when I want to render like `product.talla_L.cantidad`

```
const ProductDetails = (props) => {
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { product, loading, error } = productDetails;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    let id = props.match.params.id;
    dispatch(detailsProduct(id));
    return () => {
      //
    };
  }, []);

  console.log(product);

  return (
    <div className="textWhite">
      <div className="link-style123">
        <Link to="/ropa">Volver</Link>
      </div>
      {loading ? (
        <div>loading...</div>
      ) : error ? (
        <div>{error}</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="details">
          <div>
            <p>img-url: {product.imagen}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <h4>{product.tipo}</h4>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h4>{product.color}</h4>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h4>{product.precio}</h4>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>

              <li>
                <h4>{product.talla_L.cantidad}</h4>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default ProductDetails;
```

Here's my Redux Store settings

```js
const initialState = {}
const reducer = combineReducers({
    //states
    clothesList : clothesListReducer,
    productDetails: clothesDetailsReducer,
    userList: userSigninReducer
})

// Redux Devtools Google ext config, Delete on production step
const composeEnchancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState, composeEnchancer(applyMiddleware(thunk)))
export default store
```

Here's the Action file

```js
const detailsProduct = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: productId });
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/clothes/get/${productId}`);
    dispatch({ 
        type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS, 
        payload: data.result 
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ 
        type: PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL, 
        payload: error.message 
    });
  }
};
```

Here's The Reduccer file

```js
const clothesDetailsReducer = (state = { product: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, product: action.payload };
    case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```
{
  color: "Amarllo"
  imagen: "noImg"
  precio: 7000
  talla_L: {
    cantidad: 6
    talla: "L"
 },
  talla_M: {
    cantidad: 2
    talla: "M"
  },
  talla_S: {
    cantidad: 6
    talla: "S"
  }
}
```

> - Here's the [Img of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw7Jb.png) when i try rendering `product.talla_L.cantidad`
> - And the [Img of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Vjw.png) when i dont try rendering

I don't understand why it won't let me render the product.talla_L.cantidad object when there doesn't seem to be something wrong with the response of my API

> PD: I already tried to destructuring object props by sending props to a component, but throws me the same result

> PD2: I have added information from my redux files so that you better understand the composition of my code and help me find what goes wrong when I try to render that object

Comment: you can see the second product log was undefined. You got NullpointerException at that step https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3Vjw.png

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `product` value is undefined in the first render. Before returning your component markup check if `product` has the value you need. And if it doesn't, stop the rendering by returning `null`.

When `product` has the correct values it will render properly.

```
const ProductDetails = (props) => {
  const productDetails = useSelector((state) => state.productDetails);
  const { product, loading, error } = productDetails;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    let id = props.match.params.id;
    dispatch(detailsProduct(id));
    return () => {
      //
    };
  }, []);

  console.log(product);

  // Check the value before rendering.
  if (!product) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="textWhite">
      <div className="link-style123">
        <Link to="/ropa">Volver</Link>
      </div>
      {loading ? (
        <div>loading...</div>
      ) : error ? (
        <div>{error}</div>
      ) : (
        <div className="details">
          <div>
            <p>img-url: {product.imagen}</p>
          </div>
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <h4>{product.tipo}</h4>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h4>{product.color}</h4>
              </li>
              <li>
                <h4>{product.precio}</h4>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul>

              <li>
                <h4>{product.talla_L.cantidad}</h4>
              </li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
export default ProductDetails;
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the undefined of my console.log but it doesn't solve the error of my `product.talla_L.cantidad` rendering.